# Ansible include multiple tasks with loop

Tags: ansible, yaml, devops, hashicorp

Task1 - `create_user.yml`: Creates users via API

Task2 - `add_user_to_group.yml`: Adds users to the group via API:

Task3 - Creates and adds users to the Group by calling/including Task1 & Task2

**Task3**

```
- name: Creating the User and Adding to the Group ...
  include_tasks: create_user.yml
  loop: "{{ userslist | flatten(levels=1) }}"  
  vars:
    userslist:
      - "{{ ['users'] | product(users) }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: tasklists
```

In the above Task3, I have users dictionary as variables for Task1(`create_user.yml`).

How do I `also` include Task2(`add_user_to_group.yml`) in the above Task3?.

We can loop over multiple `include_tasks` for Task1 and Task2 but I l already have a loop in Task3.

I want to keep the Task1 and Task2 independent of each other and so not including Task2 in Task1.

How do I include multiple tasks in Task3 in my case?

Comment: Create a file which includes both in 2 different tasks and loop over an include to that file.

Comment: I created Task3 to include and loop over Task1 and Task2. You mean, to create another Task4 and include Task3 & Task2 in it?

Comment: No. You cannot include several files in the same task. I mean create a file with to include tasks (create user and add user to group) and include that file in a loop in wherever it is sutied in your situation. The loop variable on the include will be available to both other includes in the target file.

Answer (score 1):

Since my comment probably requires at least some pseudo code to be understandable, here we go.

Note that I just reused your existing vars and loops in the question without knowing if they actually do the job. So you may still have some bits and pieces to fix.

1. keep your `create_user.yml` and `add_user_to_group.yml` as they are if your really want to keep them totally independent. (You can always move those tasks to the next file later if you feel your design is too complicated)
2. create a `create_and_add_user_to_group.yml` file with the following tasks:

   ```yaml
   ---
   - name: Include create user tasks
     include_tasks: create_user.yml

   - name: include add user to group tasks
     include_tasks: add_user_to_group.yml
   ```
3. In your main task file (playbook, role, etc.....) add the following task:

   ```yaml
   - name: Create user and add to group
     include_tasks: create_and_add_user_to_group.yml
     loop: "{{ userslist | flatten(levels=1) }}"  
     vars:
       userslist:
         - "{{ ['users'] | product(users) }}"
     loop_control:
       loop_var: tasklists
   ```